I ocasionally have console app opened in full screen - how exit it?
Working in Kubuntu 22.04 I periodically by hitting some hot keys( I suppose CTRL+ALT+F4 - not sure actually) I ocasionally
have console app opened in full screen and I can not return to my OS desktop.
I proposed to enter login/password of root user and all I can do it to restart my OS with
restart command.
a) Which hot keys are there?
b) Where can I disable them?
c) Can I return to my OS desktop from this console ?

I'm not sure what you're meaning, but have you tried F11?   (it'll toggle a window go full-screen; and I wonder if you've entered that mode) as I've assumed a graphic terminal

Press Ctrl+Alt+F1 or Ctrl+Alt+F2 to return back to the graphical environment. I don't know a method on how to disable this and I don't recommend it either.

Fn+Fn7 or Fn7 or Alt+Fn+Fn7
